# Kendo UI For Angular 2 Combobox design

Tags: combobox, floating, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to customize the current combobox to floating label combo box as per attachment? Or will kendo ui for angular 2 team release this kind of design for combobox?[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on 'floating label'? Could you share an example that demonstrates the desired behavior?

Comment: You can refer to ng-material autocomplete floating label control . we need the design like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Indeed, such functionality is not supported right now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, such rendering is not supported, and it is not part of the roadmap at this point.